# Iterate through result of find operation in Mongokitten

Tags: swift4, mongokitten

I query for elements on MongoDB and receive 2 elements.
But I cannot iterate through the CollectionSlice.
Any Ideas?

Here's the code:

```
let elements = database.getAllElements()
do {
    try print("Received: \(elements.count()) elements")
    } catch {
      print(error)
    }
for element in elements {
   print(element)  // ==> should print out the element
}
let documents: [Document] = Array(elements)
for document in documents {
   print(document) // ==> should print out the document
}
```

---

OUTPUT:
Received: 2 elements

// ==> There is no printout of element or document

Program ended with exit code: 0

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution: 
I have to reset the cursor, like:

```
do {
  try elements.reset()
} catch {
  print(error)
}
```

But why do I have to reset the cursor in first place? 
May somebody can answer that.

Answer (score 0):

A cursor in MongoDB is a query's result stream. Once drained, there are no more documents, meaning that re-iterating over the cursor equals continuing iterating. Since the cursor is drained, there are no more results.

Resetting the cursor effectively sends the query again and streams those results.
It's bad practice to iterate over a cursor twice and you're better off dealing with the cursor only once since this will have a significant performance impact on the application and database.